# Using Powershell to Export-Csv

Tags: powershell

below is the code I am using to find duplicates in a `CSV` and total them up.
I cant figure out how to `Export-CSV` correctly

the code below shows what I need in the terminal window

any help would be much appreciated

```
 Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem "E:\Bill3\output.csv") |         
 Group-Object -Property Code |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name='Code';Expression={$_.Name}}, 
        @{Name='Quantity';Expression={
            ($_.Group| Measure-Object -Sum -Property Quantity ).Sum
          
           
        }       
        }
```

this is how the terminal looks, this is what i would like my exported csv to look like

[image]

Comment: Pipe to `Export-CSV` after your last command?

Comment: I tried that and it wouldn't Export

Comment: @RedecIndustrial - so ... what does `wouldn't export` mean ... exactly? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have tried to Pipe `Export-CSV` at the end of the script and it creates a blank `CSV` , so you are right in pulling me up as it did export but the data didn't, I will up vote your comment as that was well spotted [grin]

Comment: Please show the part of the code where the export fails. Adding `| Export-csv file.csv -NoType` after the last `}` works for me.

Comment: if you added `| Export-csv` after the last `}` it would tell you `an empty pipeline element is not allowed`

Comment: Add it on the same line as the last `}`

Comment: @Adminofthings thank you

Comment: @RedecIndustrial - kool! it looks like AdminOfThings posted an Answer that works for you ... glad to see that you got it working. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem "E:\Bill3\output.csv") |         
 Group-Object -Property Code |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name='Code';Expression={$_.Name}}, 
        @{Name='Quantity';Expression={
            ($_.Group| Measure-Object -Sum -Property Quantity ).Sum 
        }       
    } | Export-Csv file.csv -NoType
```

---

> an empty pipeline element is not allowed

The reason you received the error message above is because of syntax issues with line continuation. The closing `}` does not continue the line. Therefore, you cannot add your `| Export-Csv` command on the next line following the last `}`. They must be on the same line. You can simply run the following code to generate your same error:

```
PS > | export-csv o.csv
At line:1 char:1
+ | export-csv o.csv
+ ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

See [Natural Line Continuators](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html#naturallinecont) for an explanation on line continuation.